# json_decode() returns null instead an array

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I am going to INSERT an array of objects into mysql via AJAX but on server side `json_decode()` returns `null`

How can i solve this?

**This is the ajax codes:**

```
let mainObj = [

    { username: 'david', password: 33456, email: 'david@gmail.com' },
    { username: 'rose', password: 3333, email: 'rose@gmail.com' },
    { username: 'adam', password: 95112, email: 'adam@gmail.com' },
    { username: 'lisa', password: 'sarlak', email: 'lisa@gmail.com' },

]



let sendMe = JSON.stringify(mainObj);



let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {


        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }


}

xhr.open("GET", "check.php?x=" + sendMe, true);
xhr.send();
```

**And the php codes (check.php):**

```
$obj= json_decode($_GET['x'], true);

$b= $obj[1]->username;


var_dump($b);
```

It returns `null` but i need it returns an array of objects which be usable in database.

Comment: `print_r($obj)` to see __what__ is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (others already wrote it..):

```
$json = '[{"username":"david","password":33456,"email":"david@gmail.com"},{"username":"rose","password":3333,"email":"rose@gmail.com"},{"username":"adam","password":95112,"email":"adam@gmail.com"},{"username":"lisa","password":"sarlak","email":"lisa@gmail.com"}]';

$decodedJson = json_decode($json, true);


// $b= $decodedJson[1]->username; // Wrong, you have an array, not object
// Correct
foreach($decodedJson as $single) {
    print_r($single["username"]."\n");
}
```

// Prints out:

```
david rose adam lisa
```

Comment: Thanks, Issue has been solved and i can see ```username``` and other paramers in html page but in ```check.php``` it still return ```null``` do you have any idea why doesn't it print  in php page as well?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to treat an array as an object, `json_decode` returns an array not an object or stdclass... instead of

`$b= $obj[1]->username;`

should be

`$b= $obj[1]['username'];`

I'm assuming that you are not using any framework since the thing that you did should throw and exception so it's better to enable error reporting

```php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the second parameter `true` in `$obj= json_decode($_GET['x'], true);` your returned `$obj` will be an array. You either use:

```
$obj = json_decode($_GET['x']);
$b = $obj[1]->username;
```

or

```
$obj = json_decode($_GET['x'], true);
$b = $obj[1]['username'];
```

to get "rose".

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Thanks, Issue has been solved and i can see ```username``` and other paramers in html page but in ```check.php``` it still return ```null``` do you have any idea why doesn't it print  in php page as well?